# Storing Variables from a list in a loop Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, list, loops, variables, global

In my program I have a list with five 'Players' created by user input ,In order to determine what player achieved the highest score over two sessions each of the five players are asked the same list of questions to determine their total score which is then displayed.
The players are then asked the same questions again to determine their score for week 2

How do I store each players score as a global variable??

each player should have two seperate scores i.e Week1 and Week2

```
playerList=[]
def Playeradd():
    playerList.append(item)
def Playercreate():
    global item
    item = raw_input("Enter Player name: ")

    Playeradd()

[Playercreate()for _ in range (5)]
print "You have selected", len(playerList), "players for your squad, Your selected squad is.."

for item in playerList:
    print item

player =Playercreate
scorecheck={} # using a dictionary rather than a list. Because you only have to values to look at this to me seams the best option for displaying data.
x=0
totalscore=0
def pointsaward():
    global x, totalscore,scorecheck
    scorecheck={}
    while x < 5:
        print "Please enter score for ", playerList[x]
        for player in playerList:
            print "Did "+player+" play in the game?"
            play = raw_raw_input(" Did he play the match (yes or no?) ")
            if play == "yes":
                play1=2
                goalS= int(raw_input(" Did he score, if so how many?"))
                goalS=goalS*5
                goalA= int(raw_input(" How many assists?"))
                goalA=goalA*3
                motm= raw_input(" Did he win man of the match (yes or no?) ")
                motm1=0
                yelC1=0
                redC1=0
                PenM1=0
                if motm == "yes":
                    motm1=5 #this was missing from the math in total points
                else:
                    motm1=0
                yelC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a yellow card (yes or no?) ")
                if yelC == "yes":
                    yelC1= -1
                else:
                    yelC1=0
                redC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a red card (yes or no?) ")
                if redC == "yes":
                    redC1= -5
                else:
                    redC1=0                              
                PenM=raw_input(" Did he miss a peno(yes or no?) ")
                if PenM == "yes":
                    PenM1= -3
                else:
                    PenM1=0
                playerpoint1= play1+goalS+goalA+yelC1+redC1+PenM1+motm1
                scorecheck[playerList[x]] = playerpoint1
                x+= 1
            else:
                play1=0
                scorecheck[playerList[x]] = (player+" did not play")
                x+= 1

def printResults(): # added a simple function run the point adding function and print the results.
    pointsaward()
    print "This player has scored a total of ", scorecheck, " this week "
printResults()
```

Comment: Have you begun any code for this that you can provide? You don't need to post *all* of the code, but just some short snippets that focus on the issue and help us better understand your problem.

Comment: @downshift I have the code up now sorry

Comment: I saw it thank you :). I've been reviewing it, and it looks like you already have the global `scorecheck={}`. I think this already works as a dictionary for each players score, does it not? Since you can do `scorecheck['player_name']` to get that `player_name`'s score.

Comment: but as for the requirement of each player should have two seperate scores(Week1 and Week2), I think one way to do it is that we can convert the `scorecheck={}` from just a dictionary, to a list of dictionaries (i.e. a list of weeks, each week containing the players scores?) that would be `scorecheck=[{}]`. But if this would work, I'm currently stuck on how to append the scores to the list, like `scorecheck.append()`... what do you think?

Comment: @downshift the `scorecheck={}` was a suggestion from another user I originally had it as a list `scorecheck=[]` I'm still very green and have no experience using dictionaries. 

Currently it will collect the scores from each player and print a list at the of each player and their score, Still working on getting it loop and ask them for week 2. While keeping the scores from week 1 seperate

Comment: Ah I see, okay sounds good. I think the suggestion from the other user should work, for one week, but since we want 2 weeks, a list will work for that. I'll report back if I can get the weeks to append to a list, but since you are more familiar with your code (and you're already somewhat familiar with lists), try changing `scorecheck={}` to `scorecheck=[{}]`, then figure out how to append `playerList[x]` to the `scorecheck=[{}]` list. I'll do the same

Comment: Hi @Grimble6, I am very sorry for not getting back to you sooner, today was unexpectedly busy here at work --  after I looked closer at your code, I realized all the advice I gave you earlier was *WAY* too complicate, and also *VERY* incorrect, I apologize if I may have confused you. Anyways, I have a possible (but still not working perfectly the way you'll want it) code for getting the players scores for 2 weeks of games, let me know what you think and if you need more help: https://repl.it/H0qh/1

Comment: @downshift that works a lot better then any attempts I have made so far, Im having trouble organising it into A: Top overall points scored and B: Top goals scored, Sorry for the late reply

Comment: Top overall points scored organized by player, or by week?

Comment: @downshift  Like  after week one two lists, List of Goal scorers sorted from high to low , then another but of total points achieved.

Then the same for week 2, 
Then an overall total which will be the lists from week1 and 2 combined and overall goal scored which is the lists from week 1 and 2 combined.
sorry if confusing

Comment: If you use the `for`-loop at the bottom of the code I linked to, getting the two lists for each week can be done with the built-in functions `sorted()` and `sum()`, so like: `for week in range(weeks): print sorted(weeks_scores)[week];
        print sum(weeks_scores[week])`

Comment: @downshift Ah I get you, So if I want keep track of how many goals each player scored over two weeks should I create another list to store it?

Comment: sure you could do that. what you should do depends on how the goals for each player is getting saved, which currently looks like it's input as an integer `goalS`, that gets summed up to total `playerpoint1`. Since we have no way of getting back the `goalS` value after the user input is finished, the *easiest and quickest* way to get it may be just creating a new list of goal totals for each player. It may get confusing having so many lists for each player, but unless you want to re-write the code, it may be the best way to do it with the current code.

Comment: Alternatively, (for future) this is where `dictionaries` of players would have come in helpful, each player would be a dictionary that would have `keys()`: play1, goalS, goalA, yelC1, redC1, PenM1, motm1.  and each would correspond to the values. then you could get player1['goalS'].. But, forget that for now, as you said you're still green and have no experience with using dictionaries, But they are not necessary in this situation - maybe in future they would make things easier..

Comment: @downshift when I tried  `for week in range(weeks): print sorted(weeks_scores)[week]; print sum(weeks_scores[week])`

I keep getting the error                                                                                                                        




`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/thumb.py", line 82, in <module>
    printResults()
  File "C:/Python27/thumb.py", line 81, in printResults
    for week in range(weeks): print sorted(weeks_scores)[week]; print sum(weeks_scores[week])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: When I try and display the total of the two weeks it is only printing the second weeks numbers eg week1-player1=10 + week2-player2=5.
The program just prints 5 instead of 15

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the error you're getting. In the meantime, could you post the code you are running on http://repl.it/ or someplace that we can share and run the same code?

Comment: I think that error is because the `weeks_scores[week]` contain dictionaries of strings (`str`) for the keys, and integers (`int`) for the values, we only want to sum the values, so try changing the `for`-loop in your code line 81 to: `for week in range(weeks):
        print sorted(weeks_scores)[week]
        print sum(weeks_scores[week].values())`

Answer (score 0):

I have added a new variable to be used to store the total of each week:

`weekly_scores= {}`

I have added a separate function in order to add up all the scores week after week:

Check comments in code block to see explanations.

```
def combineScores():
    global scorecheck, weekly_scores
    print "These player have scored a total of ", scorecheck, " this week "

#this for loop is used to define the scores for any case of players playing or not.    
    for player in scorecheck:
        # if the player has never played a game this season prior to this week.
        if player not in weekly_scores:
            # if player did not play this season or this game           
            if scorecheck[player] == (player+" did not play"):
                weekly_scores[player] = 0
            # player did not play prior to this week but did play this week.
            else:
                newScore = scorecheck[player]   
                weekly_scores[player] = newScore
                print player+" combined score : "+str(newScore)
        # Player has played prior to this weeks game
        else:
            # played prior to this week but did not play this week.
            if scorecheck[player] == (player+" did not play"):  
                oldScore = weekly_scores[player]
                newScore = 0  
                combined = oldScore+newScore
                weekly_scores[player] = combined
                print player+" combined score : "+str(combined)
            #played prior to this week and played this week also
            else:
                oldScore = weekly_scores[player]
                newScore = scorecheck[player]  
                combined = oldScore+newScore
                weekly_scores[player] = combined
                print player+" combined score : "+str(combined)

# Having this allows me to keep track of the scores for the entire season
# and takes into account when the player is not in every game.
```

at the end of the code I just called `printResults()` over and over fore each week I wanted to add to the total results. This is just for example reason. I would define a function if I were you to decide on how many weeks you want to record then call `printResults()` that many times.

Below is the full working code I have for you:  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
playerList=[]
def Playeradd():
    playerList.append(item)
def Playercreate():
    global item
    item = raw_input("Enter Player name: ")

    Playeradd()

[Playercreate()for _ in range (5)]
print "You have selected", len(playerList), "players for your squad, Your selected squad is.."

for item in playerList:
    print item

player =Playercreate
scorecheck={} # using a dictionary rather than a list. Because you only have to values to look at this to me seams the best option for displaying data.

totalscore=0

weekly_scores= {}

def pointsaward():
    global totalscore,scorecheck
    x=0
    while x < 5:
        print ("Please enter score for ", playerList[x])
        for player in playerList:
            print "Did "+player+" play in the game?"
            play = raw_input(" Did he play the match (yes or no?) ")
            if play == "yes":
                play1=2
                goalS= int(raw_input(" Did he score, if so how many?"))
                goalS=goalS*5
                goalA= int(raw_input(" How many assists?"))
                goalA=goalA*3
                motm= raw_input(" Did he win man of the match (yes or no?) ")
                motm1=0
                yelC1=0
                redC1=0
                PenM1=0
                if motm == "yes":
                    motm1=5 #this was missing from the math in total points
                else:
                    motm1=0
                yelC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a yellow card (yes or no?) ")
                if yelC == "yes":
                    yelC1= -1
                else:
                    yelC1=0
                redC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a red card (yes or no?) ")
                if redC == "yes":
                    redC1= -5
                else:
                    redC1=0                              
                PenM=raw_input(" Did he miss a peno(yes or no?) ")
                if PenM == "yes":
                    PenM1= -3
                else:
                    PenM1=0
                playerpoint1= play1+goalS+goalA+yelC1+redC1+PenM1+motm1
                scorecheck[playerList[x]] = playerpoint1
                x+= 1
            else:
                play1=0
                scorecheck[playerList[x]] = (player+" did not play")
                x+= 1
    combineScores()

def printResults(): # added a simple function run the point adding function and print the results.
    pointsaward()
    #print "These player has scored a total of ", scorecheck, " this week "


def combineScores():
    global scorecheck, weekly_scores

    print ("These player has scored a total of ", scorecheck, " this week ")
    print()

    for player in scorecheck:
        if player not in weekly_scores:            
            if scorecheck[player] == (player+" did not play"):
                weekly_scores[player] = 0
            else:
                newScore = scorecheck[player]   
                weekly_scores[player] = newScore
                print player+" combined score : "+str(newScore)

        else:
            if scorecheck[player] == (player+" did not play"):  
                oldScore = weekly_scores[player]
                newScore = 0  
                combined = oldScore+newScore
                weekly_scores[player] = combined
                print player+" combined score : "+str(combined)
            else:
                oldScore = weekly_scores[player]
                newScore = scorecheck[player]  
                combined = oldScore+newScore
                weekly_scores[player] = combined
                print player+" combined score : "+str(combined)
printResults()
#second_week = 
printResults()
#third_week = 
printResults()
#fourth_week = 
printResults()
#and so on ...
```

Comment: When I tried to run the code I recieved errors

`'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/HUH.py", line 93, in <module>
    printResults()
  File "C:/Python27/HUH.py", line 71, in printResults
    pointsaward()
  File "C:/Python27/HUH.py", line 68, in pointsaward
    combineScores()
  File "C:/Python27/HUH.py", line 88, in combineScores
    oldScore = weekly_scores[player]
KeyError: 'James'`

Comment: @Grimble6 Ok I think I have worked out the bugs. Let me know what you get. Edit: Had to add the code to both sections. My bad

Comment: @Gimpble6: Just check if you issue was resolved on this one.